# React Custom Roulette how to show the roulette number

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-functional-component

[image]

[> - - DEMO CODE - - <](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-greider-pfkib)

The problem is to show the number when the roulette wheel is stopped.

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, option: 10 },
  { id: 2, option: -30 },
  { id: 3, option: 50 },
  { id: 4, option: 30 },
  { id: 5, option: 40 },
  { id: 6, option: 20 }
];

export default () => {
  const [mustSpin, setMustSpin] = useState(false);
  const [prizeNumber, setPrizeNumber] = useState(0);

  const handleSpinClick = () => {
    const newPrizeNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
    setPrizeNumber(newPrizeNumber);
    setMustSpin(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center">Roulette Game</h1>
        <hr />
        <Wheel
          mustStartSpinning={mustSpin}
          prizeNumber={prizeNumber}
          data={data}
          outerBorderColor={["#f2f2f2"]}
          outerBorderWidth={[25]}
          innerBorderColor={["#f2f2f2"]}
          radiusLineColor={["#dedede"]}
          radiusLineWidth={[10]}
          textColors={["#ffffff"]}
          fontSize={[50]}
          perpendicularText={[true]}
          backgroundColors={[
            "#F22B35",
            "#F99533",
            "#24CA69",
            "#514E50",
            "#46AEFF",
            "#9145B7"
          ]}
          onStopSpinning={() => {
            setMustSpin(false);
          }}
        />
        <button className="button2" onClick={handleSpinClick}>
          SPIN
        </button>
        <br />
        {data.option}
        <hr />
      </div>
```

I entered this code above but it shows the const data array id = [{ id: 1, option: 10 },{ id: 2, option: -30 },{ id: 3, option: 50 },{ id: 4 , option: 30 },{ id: 5, option: 40 },{ id: 6, option: 20 }
];

I try this but fail

```
{data.option}
```

Comment: Please try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code with issue. Codesandbox link is nice, but the question should include a "snapshot" of the code as it is now... links tend to decay over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array, so it likely won't have an `option` property.

It seems `prizeNumber` is the psuedo-random index, so to display the option access it from the `data` array.

```
{data[prizeNumber].option}
```

Comment: When I click on "SPIN" it already shows the result, perfect. Would it be possible to show the result when the spin ends? Or leave it with a delay?

Comment: @André Sure, you can conditionally hide the result while the wheel is spinning with `{!mustSpin && data[prizeNumber].option}` or if you want a bit more control over it you can add more state for when you want it displayed and handle it additionally in the `onStopSpinning` callback. You may need to add some additional logic to also not display the "result" until ***after*** the first spin.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I know it's a simple thing, but I'm starting and it's still not clear lol, thanks for your time

Comment: @André No worries, we all started *somewhere*. Is my additional comment still unclear, or was that what cleared something up for you?

Comment: That was exactly it. Through a condition when it is true it shows the spin number, perfect

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for an object property inside an array.
Try this:

```
onStopSpinning={() => {
    setMustSpin(false);
    alert(data[prizeNumber].option)
}}
```